# Azure MobileServiceClient Installationid not renewed after uninstalling mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Backend App service and [mobile app js client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client) for my cordova mobile app. As per documentation on below link InstallationIs should be renewed on every app installation.

[Introducing InstallationId](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2016/01/22/adding-push-notification-tags-from-an-azure-mobile-apps-client/)

The problem is when I un-install and install the app it creates same Installation id. If I restart the device after uninstall then it creates new InstallationId on install.

Is there a way to forcefully renew the InstallationId from JS code so that restart can be avoided?

Comment: What's your target platform? I checked the method **getApplicationInstallationId** under [MobileServiceClient.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/08de350b858b6adafe25cd985a924769bd6cef42/sdk/src/MobileServiceClient.js), per my understanding, you may retrieve the new installationId after un-stall and install the app. You could try to check the source code of the Javascript Clients for Azure Mobile Apps to narrow this issue, or you may implement the local storage for the installationId by yourself.

Comment: target platform is android. Using cordova 8.0. Somehow i have handled the logic at backend. I will further drill to narrow down the issue. Thanks Bruce Chen.